# Get a textbox to fill 100% of the width of its container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form, in which there's a textbox followed by a submit button in the same row.

I'd like the submit button to be a little small but the textbox to take up all of the remaining width.

So, I'd like to just stretch the textbox to fill all the width but for the width required by the button.

However, at present, my UI looks like so:

[image]

Notice all the empty horizontal space between the textbox and the button.

I have tried setting the width of the textbox to 100% in the CSS but nothing happens.

Below is my HTML.

```
<div class="row" id="rowFormContainer">
    <form id="frm">
        <div id="divUserURLContainer" class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" 
                   id="txtUserURL" 
                   placeholder="Stack Overflow URL" />
        </div>

        <div id="divGetButtonContainer" class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Get" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

As you may observe, I am using the bootstrap classes `row` and `md-col-x` in order to define the layout of the container `divs`. I'd like the `input` control that reresents my textbox to fill 100% of the width of its container `div`.

And this is my CSS:

```
#rowFormContainer {
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
}

#divUserURLContainer {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;

    padding: 0px;
}

#txtUserURL {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: cadetblue;
    font-size: 22px;

    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;

    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code on JSBin, codepen or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use flex like this :

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}

input[type="text"] {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="rowFormContainer">
  <form id="frm">
    <input type="text" id="txtUserURL" placeholder="Stack Overflow URL" />
    <input type="submit" value="Get" class="btn btn-success" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both of you. Actually, all this while since you both posted your answers, I had been battling with my code trying out both your solutions. For some reason, neither of them worked for me. Until now. I was banging my head in frustration and I just now discovered why they didn't work. It was because another CSS file in the hierarchy set the `max-width` on input controls to `280px`. I removed that and both your solutions worked. I have to choose just one as the correct answer, though. And since this one is much simpler, I am choosing it. I like both your answers, though. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the native bootstrap functionality correctly - by adding the class - "form-control" to your input you will achieve the full width input - without resorting to flex. Note that I have the .form-group wrapper and added a label - it is good practise to include a label with your inputs - and thee "control-label" class on that allows bootstrap to color it red if there is an error (and the ".has-error" class is applied to the form group.

I have added borders around the two divs. Not that there is padding within the div - because that is natural 15px padding of divs that bootstrap provides - not be cause the input does not extend the full width.

And following the craziness inspired by comments - I have removed padding to show the implications of such an action - simply by removing the left and right padding - I do not think this is very desirable - but I accept that the OP asked for the full width of the div. However crazy that is.

Note that due to the size of the nsnippet editor - i had to make it col-xs-10 / col-xs-2 - but the same premise holds up through the viewport breakpoints.

```
  <div id="divUserURLContainer" class="col-md-10">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="txtUserURL">Label text</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUserURL" placeholder="Stack Overflow URL" >/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```css
#divGetButtonContainer {
padding-top:24px;
padding-bottom: 16px;
}

#divUserURLContainer,
#divGetButtonContainer {
border: solid 1px red;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
}

 #divGetButtonContainer{
border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
<div id="divUserURLContainer" class="col-xs-10">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="txtUserURL">Label text</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUserURL" placeholder="Stack Overflow URL"/ >
    </div>
  </div>
   <div id="divGetButtonContainer" class="col-xs-2">
     
      <input type="submit" value="Get" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: And where is the submit button ? the OP is not searching to make the input text full width

Comment: now after adding the button you are replication the same behavior of the OP. You have spaces and he said : `So, I'd like to just stretch the textbox to fill all the width`

Comment: My comment is not ridiculous ... read carefully the question, the OP, you, and me know how to use Bootsrap. Now he don't want these spaces that are coming from bootstrap to be there. The question is not about the use of bootstrap

Comment: @Temani Afif - You should probably learn the intricacies of Bootstrap CSS and understand that the natural styling of hte column designated divs is to add 15px padding to either side. This accounts for the -15px marging on the sides that the div.row applies. Therefore the input IS extending full width of the div - minus the Bootstrap padding. This can be removed of course - but style rules - but its therefore a reason. This answer applies the full width of the input as requested. If the padding is to be removed - padding-left: 0; padding-right:0

Comment: @TemaniAfif - And following the craziness inspired by comments - I have removed padding to show the implications of such an action - simply by removing the left and right padding - I do not think this is very desirable - but I accept that the OP asked for the full width of the div. However crazy that is.

Comment: there is no need to be rude with me like this. ... Simply read the question again and especially these 2 lines :`I'd like the submit button to be a little small but the textbox to take up **all of the remaining width.** So, I'd like to just stretch the textbox to fill **all the width** but for the width required by the button.` If you still think my comment are ridiculous, i have nothing to add ...

Comment: Thank you both of you. Actually, all this while since you both posted your answers, I had been battling with my code trying out both your solutions. For some reason, neither of them worked for me. Until now. I was banging my head in frustration and I just now discovered why they didn't work. It was because another CSS file in the hierarchy set the `max-width` on input controls to `280px`. I removed that and both your solutions worked. I have to choose just one as the correct answer, though. Since the flex one is much simpler, I am choosing it. I like both your answers, though. Thanks so much.